# Prove using Greens Theorem that the line integral is independent of curve C

Tags: vector-analysis, harmonic-analysis, greens-theorem

Let f :
$R^2$ → R be a twice continuously differentiable scalar field which is harmonic,
that is, $∇^2$
f = 0. Use Green’s Theorem to prove that the line integral
$$\int_c {df\over dy}dx-{df\over dx}dy$$

is independent of curve C in the (xy)-plane.

$$so far $$
I have worked out that
∇ x f=0 for the graph being irrotational
I'm not sure this is relevant to be honest
I know f is conservative if it is the gradient of a scalar field as well and I think conservative and independent are the same in this sense I'm not sure how to take the gradient I've tried to apply greens theorem making ${df\over dy}$ =     and $-{df\over dx}$=Q but the answers just look plain wrong to me can anyone help

my application gave me $2 \int \int_R {d^2f\over dxdy}$dxdy  if that is right I don't know how it proves independence.

Comment: What did you get for that line integral when you applied Green's Theorem?

Comment: i edited the question to show you

Comment: I am not sure I applied it in the right direction for the question this has had me flummoxed for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply Green's Theorem, we have to have a closed curve that encloses a region. $C$ itself might not be closed. The phrase "independent of curve $C$" means that as long as two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ start and end at the same point, then they will give the same line integral. On a piece of paper, draw a random curve $C_1$ and then draw another curve $C_2$ starting and ending at the same point. Notice that this now encloses a region. Call it $R$.

Then Green's Theorem says that along the curve $C=C_1-C_2$, which is the path along $C_1$ and then back to the beginning along $C_2$, we have $$\int_C Pdx+Qdy=\iint_R\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dA$$

So we actually get $$\iint_R\left(-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)dA=-\iint_R\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)dA$$

Now we need to use the fact that $f$ is harmonic. What does this tell us?

Comment: does f being harmonic tell us that the last equations the d^2 f and so on = 0

Comment: so we integrate 0

Comment: Harmonic doesn't tell us that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$ are both $0$, but yes, it does tell us that the sum that is in that integral is $0$. Therefore $\int_C (\dots)$, which equals $\int_{C_1}(\dots) - \int_{C_2}(\dots)$, is $0$.

Comment: and does this sum being equal to 0 show independence

Comment: The phrase "independent of curve C" means that as long as two curves C1 and C2 start and end at the same point, then they will give the same line integral. So we need to get $\int_{C_1}(\dots)=\int_{C_2}(\dots)$. Do you see how to get there?

Comment: well if the integral for c1 - the integral of c2 = 0 then the integral of c1 must = 0 so the integral of c1 must = the integral of c2

Comment: thank you so much for your help you have been an excellent and patient teacher

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this does not mean $\int_{C_1}(\dots)$ and $\int_{C_2}(\dots)$ are each $0$, just that they are equal.

Comment: yes they are not both 0 but the have the same value thank you